# apply chi² test on a list

Tags: r, list, chi-squared

I would like to apply a chi² test on a list.
First I would like to apply the test on every dataset starting with the same name and number (option1a, option 1b, ...) , later between ALL the datasets with same number and letter (option 1a, option 2a, ...3a, ...4a, and for ...1b, ...2b, etc...) and after that chi² test within the lines (example chi²test for option1a=c(1, 3, NA, 5, 3, 1, NA, 3, 1, NA, 3, 5, 5, NA, 1, 3, 5). I have already tried a lot, but unsuccessfully.

Here's the data

```
data <- data.frame(option1a=c(1, 3, NA, 5, 3, 1, NA, 3, 1, NA, 3, 5, 5, NA, 1, 3, 5),
              option1b=c(NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 5, 5, 3, 1, NA, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA),
              option2a=c(1, 3, NA, 5, 5, 1, NA, 1, 1, 3, NA, 5, 1, 3, 5, 3, NA),
              option2b=c(3, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, 5, 3, 1, 1, 3), 
              option2c=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
              option3a=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
              option3b=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)) #option4a, option4b and so on...


grouped <- as.data.frame(sub("^(.{7}).*", "\\1", colnames(data)))  

list <- lapply(split(colnames(data), grouped), function(x) data[x])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the data? Are the values in each column frequencies or categories? For option1a and option2a do you want `xtabs(~option1a+option2a, data)` or `as.matrix(data[1:2, ])`. Remove option3a/b from your example since the values are all missing.

Comment: The values are categories. I need xtabs(~option1a+option2a, data) for chi²-test between groups (option1a option1b etc.)and as.matrix(data[1:2, ]) probably for chi²-test between categories within the group. And option 3a/b can be removed. It's just an example data given, my list has much more data...

Comment: Try `lapply(list, function(x) chisq.test(na.omit(x)))`.

Comment: Error in chisq.test(na.omit(x)) : 
at least one entry of 'x' must be positive

Comment: Drop the last two columns from your example data since they are entirely NAs and therefore have no positive values.

Comment: Do you may have a code for me removing NAs out of the list? Like complete.cases or something like that. Drop_na and na.omit delete almost everything...

Comment: First drop the last 3 columns (not 2 as I said before) which are all NAs by using`data <- data[, 1:4]`. Then create `grouped` and `list` to create a list of two data frames. Finally `lapply(list, function(x) chisq.test(na.omit(x)))` will give the chi squares for the first two tables. Missing values will be deleted from those tables by rows. You cannot compute chi square on a row with missing values. Look at the output of `lapply(list, na.omit)`. You will get warning messages that the chi square approximation may be incorrect because the counts are very low in your example tables.

Comment: It's just I need a code to find NA columns in my big data set, not the example one here. Can't search and remove them all manually.

Comment: I've provided code to remove then when running chi square. Why is that not sufficient? R has functions such as `complete.cases()` to remove cases/rows with missing values. My code just removes rows with missing values in the table being used. If the answer so far is not sufficient, provide reproducible data and show exactly what outcome you expect.

Comment: I would, but I really don't find the reason why. I don't know where is the difference in the data, that it's working here in stackoverflow, but not for my data. It completely looks the same. Still shows the error: Error in chisq.test(na.omit(x)) : 
at least one entry of 'x' must be positive

Comment: With debugging it tells me this source is not available: correct = TRUE, p = rep(1/length(x) - already in line 1